# Programmatically adding User Defined Runtime Attributes for buttons iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a bunch of buttons on my iOS7 app layout and when I manually add layer.masksToBundle boolean true and layer.CornerRadius number 6 to my buttons some of them are taking and some of them are not. I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically add these attributed for all buttons.

Comment: Well, for one thing their names are not `masksToBundle` and `CornerRadius`. Getting the names right is crucial. It's a problem because you can type any string into the runtime attributes: you don't get any compiler checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a Custom button (as opposed to a System button), you can subclass UIButton (such that the button sets its own masking and corner radius) and use the subclass throughout.